# Subclassing int and overriding the __init__ method - Python

Tags: python, int, subclassing, built-in

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [inheritance from str or int](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2673651/inheritance-from-str-or-int)

Hi folks,

I'm trying to subclass the int class without any success. Here is my attempt:

```
class SpecialInt(int):
    def __init__(self, x, base=10, important_text=''):
        int.__init__(self, x, base)
        self.important_text=important_text
```

If I perform the following:

```
integer = SpecialInt(123, 10, 'rage of the unicorns')
```

I get this error:

```
TypeRror: int() takes at most 2 arguments (3 given)
```

---

Any ideas? :)

Comment: Duplicate. See here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2673651/inheritance-from-str-or-int

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3238350/subclassing-int-in-python

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3238350/subclassing-int-in-python

Answer (score 9):

See [`__new__`](http://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html#object.__new__):

> `__new__`() is intended mainly to allow subclasses of immutable types (like int, str, or tuple) to customize instance creation. It is also commonly overridden in custom metaclasses in order to customize class creation.