# Swap keys for values in dictionary with multiple duplicate values in Python 3

Tags: python, dictionary, set

I know how to swap keys and values in a dictionary, but I don't know what I should do if I want to make a set as a value for those multiple keys that correspond with that value.

I have the following code:

```
def bind(dict1):
dict2 = {}
for k, v in dict1.items():
    dict2[v] = {k}
return dict2
```

The problem is, if I enter for instance

```
bind({'Europa': 'Jupiter', 'Psamathe': 'Neptune', 'Cordelia': 'Uranus', 'Cupid': 'Uranus'})
```

It would return the following:

```
{'Jupiter': {'Europa'}, 'Neptune': {'Psamathe'}, 'Uranus': {'Cupid'}}
```

while I need to have:

```
{'Jupiter': {'Europa'}, 'Neptune': {'Psamathe'}, 'Uranus': {'Cupid', 'Cordelia'}}
```

I have tried to make empty sets as values for my new dictionary by entering:

```
def bind(dict1):
dict2 = {}
for k, v in dict1.items():
    dict2[v] = {}
return dict2
```

But how can I add values to the corresponding sets belonging to the key `dict2[v]`?

Comment: possible duplicate of [make dictionary with duplicate keys in python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10664856/make-dictionary-with-duplicate-keys-in-python)

Answer (score 3):

You could use a [`defaultdict`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict).

```
from collections import defaultdict
swapped = defaultdict(set)
for k, v in source.iteritems():
    swapped[v].add(k)
```

`defaultdict` transparently creates a value at any as-yet-unaccessed key using the callable provided as the initialization argument as a factory.  The above is basically equivalent to:

```
swapped = {}
for k, v in source.iteritems():
    if v not in swapped:
        swapped[v] = set()
    swapped[v].add(k)
```

Comment: Documentation for the defaultdict: http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict

Comment: Thanks, added link to answer.

Answer (score 2):

```
import collections
def bind(dict1):
    dict2 = collections.defaultdict(set)
    for k, v in dict1.items():
        dict2[v].add(k)
    return dict2

result = bind({'Europa': 'Jupiter', 'Psamathe': 'Neptune', 'Cordelia': 'Uranus', 'Cupid': 'Uranus'})
print(result)
```

yields

> defaultdict(, {'Jupiter': set(['Europa']), 'Neptune':
>   set(['Psamathe']), 'Uranus': set(['Cordelia', 'Cupid'])})

---

Alternative, you could let `dict2` be a `dict` instead of a `collections.defaultdict(set)`, and use the `setdefault` method:

```
def bind(dict1):
    dict2 = {}
    for k, v in dict1.items():
        dict2.setdefault(v,set()).add(k)
    return dict2
```

---

References:

- [set.add](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#set.add)
- [collection.defaultdict](http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict)
- [dict.setdefault](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#dict.setdefault)

Comment: Thanks! `.add` and the module `collections` is what I needed in other words. I'm very new to those dictionaries still. ;)

Comment: Right. Just be careful to note that `add` is a method of `set`, not `dict`.

Comment: Yeah, take note of @unutbu's comment.  `.add` is not the answer by itself.  You need to make sure there is already a set for the key, or do as everyone's answer has so far and use a `defaultdict`.

Comment: Yeah, `add()` is what you use because of the `set` in the `defaultdict` initialization.  If you had `list` there instead, you'd have to use `append` or `extend`.

Comment: Thanks. I just needed to return dict(dict2) and I have what I wanted. Also, I have indeed struggled with trying to use `.add`as a method of `dict`instead of of `set`. That is what summoned me here.

Answer (score 2):

```
>>> import collections
>>> out = collections.defaultdict(set)
>>> inval = {'Europa': 'Jupiter', 'Psamathe': 'Neptune', 'Cordelia': 'Uranus', 'Cupid': 'Uranus'}
>>> for k, v in inval.items():
...     out[v].add(k)
...
>>> out
defaultdict(<type 'set'>, {'Jupiter': set(['Europa']), 'Neptune': set(['Psamathe']), 'Uranus': set(['Cordelia', 'Cupid'])})
```