# python dictionary- make key-value pair opposite while some keys share same values without rewriting

Tags: python

this is the dictionary I got:
`dict1 = {'A': 1, 'E': 1, 'I': 2, 'O': 0, 'U': 0}`

and I want to make key-value pair opposite, so I used:
`opp_dict1 = {v: k for k, v in dict1.items()}`

and I got:
`{1: 'E', 2: 'I', 0: 'U'}`

how can I get:
`{1: ['A', 'E'],  2: ['I'], 0: ['O', 'U']}`

thank you....I'm confused

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Dictionary comprehension for swapping keys/values in a dict with multiple equal values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21512152/dictionary-comprehension-for-swapping-keys-values-in-a-dict-with-multiple-equal)

Comment: Another dupe using ``defaultdict``: https://stackoverflow.com/a/16110236/4349415

Answer (score 0, accepted):

can you try the following:

```
opp_dict1 = {}
for k, v in dict1.items():
    if v in opp_dict1:
        opp_dict1[v].append(k)
    else:
        opp_dict1[v] = [k]
```

Output:

```
{1: ['A', 'E'], 2: ['I'], 0: ['O', 'U']}
```

Answer (score 0):

This must be done with a regular for loop and not a comprehension. The following does the inversion.

```
dict1 = {'A': 1, 'E': 1, 'I': 2, 'O': 0, 'U': 0}
dict2 = {}
for k, v in dict1.items():
    dict2.setdefault(v, []).append(k)
```

Answer (score 0):

try use [`defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) which means if key is not found in the dictionary then instead of a thrown the `KeyError`, create default items what you defined (like `list`, `int` ...)

```
from collections import defaultdict
d = defaultdict(list)
    for k,v in dict1.items():
        d[v].append(k)
```