# Python How can I get all values same name keys from dictionary

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

```
>>> dic = {'a': ['1a','2a','3a'],'b': ['1b','2b'], 'a' : ['4a','5a']}
```

It has same keys 'a'

and I want to get all values from this dic

but when I use

```
>>> dic.get('a')
```

It only returns

```
['4a','5a']
```

How can I get all 'a' key's values from it?

I have thought to using repetitive statement to check all keys, but it seems inefficient

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A dictionary can't store duplicate keys. One way around is to store lists or sets inside the dictionary. I'd recommend you to store values in a set pointing same keys.

```
>>> from collections import defaultdict

>>> dic = defaultdict(list)

>>> dic['a'].extend(['1a','2a','3a'])
>>> dic['a'].extend(['4a','5a'])
>>> dic['b'].extend(['1b','2b'])
```

Answer (score 2):

You say:

```
>>> dic = {'a': ['1a','2a','3a'],'b': ['1b','2b'], 'a' : ['4a','5a']}
It has same keys 'a'
```

no it doesn't:

```
>>> dic = {'a': ['1a','2a','3a'],'b': ['1b','2b'], 'a' : ['4a','5a']}
>>> dic
{'a': ['4a', '5a'], 'b': ['1b', '2b']}
```

the first occurrence of key `'a'` has simply disappeared, "trampled over" by the second occurrence of the same key.

I doubt you're building `dic` as a `dict` literal like this (I think such a literal should raise an exception, because it makes absolutely no sense, but, alas, it doesn't) -- can you show us the actual code you're using instead in order to build that `dict`?  **Then** we might suggest how to actually build the `dict` you want!-)

Answer (score 0):

Python dictionary doesn't support duplicate keys, check this thread for a solution to achive this, [make dictionary with duplicate keys in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10664856/make-dictionary-with-duplicate-keys-in-python)