# Trying to keep duplicates while making a dictionary

Tags: python, list, dictionary, for-loop

```
word = 'EVAPORATE'
lettersWord = list(word)
d = {}
for elem in lettersWord:
       d[elem] = '_'
print(d)
```

This returns:

```
{'E': '_', 'V': '_', 'A': '_', 'P': '_', 'O': '_', 'R': '_', 'T': '_'}
```

Though what I want it to return is:

```
{'E': '_', 'V': '_', 'A': '_', 'P': '_', 'O': '_', 'R': '_', 'A': '_', 'T': '_', 'E': '_'}
```

Thanks for any help!

Comment: You can't. Dictionary's keys must be unique.

Comment: Use defaultdict function. It's possible see also [link](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10664856/5025009)

Comment: In this case, a dictionary is just not the correct structure (What would `d['E']` mean?) Either use a multiset (Like `collections.Counter`) or a list `[('E', '_'), ('V', '_'), ...]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a list of the duplicate key's values:

```
from collections import defaultdict

word = 'EVAPORATE'

d = defaultdict(list)

for i in word:
    d[i].append("_")
```

Output:

```
{'A': ['_', '_'], 'E': ['_', '_'], 'O': ['_'], 'P': ['_'], 'R': ['_'], 'T': ['_'], 'V': ['_']}
```

Comment: Thanks, helped a lot!

Answer (score 0):

The keys of a dictionary must be unique, so you can't have duplicates. One way to make the keys unique in this case would be to make them a `tuple` that contains the letter and its corresponding string index.

Here's what I mean:

```
from pprint import pprint

word = 'EVAPORATE'
d = {}

for (i, letter) in enumerate(word):
       d[i, letter] = '_'

pprint(d)
```

Output:

```
{(0, 'E'): '_',
 (1, 'V'): '_',
 (2, 'A'): '_',
 (3, 'P'): '_',
 (4, 'O'): '_',
 (5, 'R'): '_',
 (6, 'A'): '_',
 (7, 'T'): '_',
 (8, 'E'): '_'}
```

Comment: Not exactly what I was looking for, but helpful nonetheless!

Comment: GauravG.: Note, too, that the index and the letter can be put in the opposite order in the tuple—whichever's the most convenient.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use some type of list data structure you could try a 2D array

Or if you are fine with using a string to show your output you could do that as well

2D array implementation

```
word = 'EVAPORATE'
lettersWord = list(word)
d = []
for elem in range(len(lettersWord)):
   d.append([])       #here we make our sublist
   d[elem].append(lettersWord[elem])    #here we append the current character of lettersWord to the current sublist
   d[elem].append('_')      #here we append the underscore as our marker


for i in d:
  print(i)
```

String implementation

```
ourString = ''

for i in word:
  ourString += i+' : _ \n'  #here we append our : _ and a newline as our marker



print(ourString)
```

Output #1:

```
 ['E', '_']
 ['V', '_']
 ['A', '_']
 ['P', '_']
 ['O', '_']
 ['R', '_']
 ['A', '_']
 ['T', '_']
 ['E', '_']
```

Output #2

```
  E : _ 
  V : _ 
  A : _ 
  P : _ 
  O : _ 
  R : _ 
  A : _ 
  T : _ 
  E : _
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Definitely did!