# repeated text parsing in python to dict

Tags: python, parsing, dictionary

I have a system which returns the output in the following format from command line.  I am trying to parse this and convert it to dict in python. A delimiter is ":" in the whole command, I just split the text with "\n" and then further split it with ":" and just keep append it to a dict, but it works fine if keys are unique but here in command output block of code is repeated. so not sure who should I parse and get all the values in a dict.
Here job till length is a repeated block of code. can have dict inside a dict or list but not sure how to repeat.

```
for d in res.split("\n"):
     r = d.split(':')
     if len(r) == 2:
        return_dict[r[0].strip()]=r[1].strip()
     else:
        continue
```

here it will over  write the job data and will only have the last values. any points will be really helful.

first name                  : John
   last name                   : mathew
     Total : 10
   Final cost          : 7000
   time       : 2017-09-12
   Result                : Pass

```
  jobs pending   : 2
  jobs completed  : 4

        job        : 0
        ID              : 42

              name         : filter_pre
              type    : zzsbcfdcd
              length       : 750

              name         : gasVacume
              type    : adfadfadkfj
              length       : 8567

        job        : 100
        ID              : 43

              name         : filter
              type    : adfadf
              length       : 800


        job       : 100
        ID              : 15

              name         : csprt
              type  : adfa
              length      : 1000
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [make dictionary with duplicate keys in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10664856/make-dictionary-with-duplicate-keys-in-python)

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10664856/make-dictionary-with-duplicate-keys-in-python

Answer (score 0):

If you want to keep duplicate keys then you should create a list of dictionaries. Change your code with this code given below.

```
final_list = []
for d in res.split("\n"):
     return_dict = {}
     r = d.split(':')
     if len(r) == 2:
        return_dict[r[0].strip()]=r[1].strip()
        final_list.append(return_dict)
     else:
        continue
print final_list
```