# zipping two lists, one containing similar elements

Tags: python, python-3.x

this might be a naive question, I have two lists, say list1 and list2.

```
list1 =[[('a', 'b'), ('c', 'd')], [('e', 'f'), ('g', 'h')]]
list2 =['aa', 'aa']
```

When I do

```
dict(zip(list2, list1))
```

I get the following

```
{'aa': [('e', 'f'), ('g', 'h')]}
```

The output I want is

{`'aa': [('a', 'b'), ('c', 'd')], 'aa': [('e', 'f'), ('g', 'h')]}`

When I change list2 to:

```
list2 = ['aa1', 'aa2']
dict(zip(list2, list1))
```

gives

```
{'aa1': [('a', 'b'), ('c', 'd')], 'aa2': [('e', 'f'), ('g', 'h')]}
```

Why I am not getting desired output in the first case? Could you please help me on this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please explain why you think this is a good idea, and what `result['aa']` should return if you have two identical keys?

Comment: You simply cannot have two identical keys in a dictionary, that's not how it works.

Comment: I  understood that, when we say dict(zip(B, A)), the original value in key 'aa' is replaced with the new one, which get printed.

Comment: A dictionary is a hash table. With hash tables, you can only have unique keys. You could use a different data structure if you want to not have unique keys. For example, you could use a tuple: `tuple(zip(list2, list1))`. Or you could use `collections.defaultdict` to append values onto an existing key if you still wanted to use a dictionary structure (and have constant lookup time).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default dict in python cannot have duplicate key, in the other hand we can have multiple values.
In the first statement, python will add the key `aa` with the value :

```
[('a', 'b'), ('c', 'd')]
```

then it will overwrite its value with :

```
 [('e', 'f'), ('g', 'h')]
```

To create dict with duplicate keys, take a look at this [make dictionary with duplicate keys in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10664856/make-dictionary-with-duplicate-keys-in-python)

Comment: This helped me alot. Thanks.