# List of variables in jinja from csv file

Tags: python, csv, jinja2

I need to print all items with identical names of columns in jinja2 template from csv file

csv file:

```
some1,letter,letter,letter,letter,some2
1,f,r,o,g,z
q,s,u,n,,a
a,f,a,c,e,q
z,n,a,n,o,1
```

i tried to use this jinj2 template:

```
{% for item in letter %}{{ item }}{% endfor %}
```

and result:

```
g

e
o
```

(only item from last "column" in csv)

but i need:

```
frog
sun
face
nano
```

Answer (score 1):

I can suggest easy, elegant and flexible way to do this is with the help of the dictionary that can store values as a list for duplicate keys. See [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10664856/make-dictionary-with-duplicate-keys-in-python) for such dictionary class. But implementation of this class can be different, I don't insist that this one is the best.

```
import csv
import os
from itertools import groupby

class DictList(dict):
    def __init__(self, iterable, **kwargs):
        super(DictList, self).__init__()
        for k, v in iterable:
            self[k] = v
        self.update(**kwargs)

    def __setitem__(self, key, value):
        try:
            # Assumes there is a list on the key
            self[key].append(value) 
        except KeyError: # if fails because there is no key
            super(DictList, self).__setitem__(key, value)
        except AttributeError: # if fails because it is not a list
            super(DictList, self).__setitem__(key, [self[key], value])


with open('test.csv') as csv_file:
    reader = csv.reader(csv_file, delimiter=',')
    header = next(reader)

    for row in reader:
        variables = DictList(zip(header, row))
```

This outputs:

```
{'some1': '1', 'letter': ['f', 'r', 'o', 'g'], 'some2': 'z'}
{'some1': 'q', 'letter': ['s', 'u', 'n', ''], 'some2': 'a'}
{'some1': 'a', 'letter': ['f', 'a', 'c', 'e'], 'some2': 'q'}
{'some1': 'z', 'letter': ['n', 'a', 'n', 'o'], 'some2': '1'}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need something like this

```py
import csv

with open('test.csv') as csv_file:
    data_lst = list(csv.reader(csv_file, delimiter=','))
    items = []
    data_without_header = data_lst[1:]
    for row in data_without_header:
        items.append("".join(row))
```

Use this in jinja

```
{% for item in items %}{{ item }}{% endfor %}
```

It would be displayed like this

```
frog
sun
face
nano
```

Comment: thank you for your answer! but i need to use jinja template. csv may see like:

a,b,c,d,e,f,letter,letter,letter,letter,z,x,g,h,i,j,k,l,m,n,o

Comment: you can use the *items* variable in jinja template.

Comment: your code do not work with csv like this:  

abrakadabra,letter,letter,letter,letter,some  
1,f,r,o,g,h  
5,s,u,n,,j  
g,f,a,c,e,l  
j,n,a,n,o,6