# Filling a dictionary with lists not works in python

Tags: python, list, dictionary

Simply, I am trying to fill up the dictionary from two lists, the first list has treated as the keys where all have the same word "text". And the second list has treated as values.

```
List_1 = ["text", "text", "text"]

List_2 = ["Programmer", "Engineer", "Art Therapist"]

data_dict = {}
for j in range(len(List_1)):
    data_dict[List_1[j]] = List_2 [j]

print(data_dict)


#Expected output:
{'text': 'Programmer', 'text': 'Engineer', 'text': 'Art Therapist'}

#What I am getting is only:
{'text': 'Art Therapist'}
```

Why overwriting is happening? Can anyone help with this?

Comment: You cannot have duplicate keys in a dictionary

Comment: Oh, really?
So, How I can achieve this scenario? {'text': 'Programmer', 'text': 'Engineer', 'text': 'Art Therapist'}

Comment: How would you expect to retrieve a value out of it?

Comment: you can not do that using `dict` atleast

Comment: @MohsenAli just think what would calling `my_dict['text']` return in that situation? You need to think about how dictionaries work, hashing keys etc.

Comment: `zip(List_1, List_2)` will give you `[('text', 'Programmer'), ('text': 'Engineer'), ('text', 'Art Therapist')]`

Comment: @ AlexisBRENON,
Your way is possible for me and helpful. Thanks

Comment: you can have `{'text':['Programmer','Engineer','Art Therapist']}` basically the value is a list.

Comment: You can use [pandas.DataFrame](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.html) as alternate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using the wrong data structure for what you want to achieve, since `dict` keys must be unique.

You could either `zip()` the two lists together (but this will still be a sequence / `list`):

```
list(zip(List_1, List_2))
# [('text', 'Programmer'), ('text', 'Engineer'), ('text', 'Art Therapist')]
```

or create a custom class implementing the functionalities you were expecting from the `dict()`. See [Make a dictionary with duplicate keys in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10664856/make-a-dictionary-with-duplicate-keys-in-python) for more info.