# For each value in list of dictionaries print corresponding value in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, for-loop, arraylist

I have a list of dictionaries and I want to do a for each to find corresponding values.

My list:

```
my_list = [{'genre':'Dystopia', 'book':'Hunger Games'},
           {'genre':'Fanstasy', 'book':'Harry Potter'},
           {'genre':'Dystopia', 'book':'Divergent'}]
```

I want to get books corresponding to the genre.

Expected result:

```
for 'Dystopia' get 'Hunger Games', 'Divergent'
for 'Fantasy' get 'Harry Potter'
```

I am not sure how to go about it. I know I need a for loop but don't know what to do beyond that.

```
for x in my_list:
   x['url']
```

Not sure what to add next.

Comment: What is the issue, exactly? That for loop looks fine to me. Why are you using a list of dictionaries for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this.

```
[dictionary['book'] for dictionary in my_list if dictionary['genre'] == 'Dystopia']
```

This goes through all of the dictionaries in `my_list` and if the `genre` is `Dystopia` it records the `book`.

Below shows how to obtain a dictionary that contains all books for each genre.

```
genres = set([dictionary['genre'] for dictionary in my_list])
result = {genre:[dictionary['book'] for dictionary in my_list if dictionary['genre'] == genre] for genre in genres}
```

Comment: I have multiple genres and want to avoid hard coding values like Dystopia. I just wanted it to return the value for each of the genres

Answer (score 0):

you want to get a dictionary of genre -> list of books,

so you need to iterate `my_list`, take the genre (as the key) and the book (as the value) and append it to the list of books in this genre

using [`defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) will easily eliminate the corner case of the first book.

```py
from collections import defaultdict

result = defaultdict(list)
for d in my_list:
  result[d['genre']].append(d['book'])
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi please find the solution below.

```
my_list = [
{'genre':'Dystopia', 'book':'Hunger Games'},
           {'genre':'Fanstasy', 'book':'Harry Potter'},
           {'genre':'Dystopia', 'book':'Divergent'}
           ]
genre_holder = dict()
for item in my_list:
    if genre_holder.get(item['genre'],"empty") == "empty":
         genre_holder[item['genre']] = list()
    genre_holder[item['genre']].append(item['book'])
print(genre_holder)

for genre in genre_holder:
    print("for ",genre," get ", ",".join(genre_holder[genre]))
```

Answer (score 0):

For a more functional approach, this return a map of the correct books:

```py
list(map(lambda x: x["book"], filter(lambda x: x["genre"] == "Dystopia", my_list)))
>>> ['Hunger Games', 'Divergent']
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this:

```
books={}
for i in my_list:
    genre=i["genre"]
    book=i["book"]
    if genre in books:
        if book in books[genre]:
            continue
    else:
        books[genre]=[]
    books[genre].append(book)

print(books)
```

output

```
{'Dystopia': ['Hunger Games', 'Divergent'], 'Fanstasy': ['Harry Potter']}
```

Answer (score 0):

From [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10664856/make-a-dictionary-with-duplicate-keys-in-python), you could try to create a new class from built-in `dict`:

```
class Dictlist(dict):
    def __setitem__(self, key, value):
        try:
            self[key]
        except KeyError:
            super(Dictlist, self).__setitem__(key, [])
        self[key].append(value)
```

So...

```
d = Dictlist()
for element in my_list:
    d[element['genre']] = d['book']
```

output:

```
{'Dystopia': ['Hunger Games', 'Divergent'], 'Fanstasy': ['Harry Potter']}
```