# Python - Issue when merging lists with repeating values into a dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

When my first lists has repeating values, it causes the merge to fail for some reason.

```
names = ['bob', 'bob', 'bob', 'bob']
id = ['15', '12', '19', '20']
rating = ['100', '90', '100', '80']

dictionary = dict(zip(names, zip(id, rating)))

print(dictionary)
```

will output

```
{'bob': ('20', '80')}
```

However, if I simply change all the names to be unique, it will output as expected.

```
names = ['bob', 'sally', 'john', 'jill']
id = ['15', '12', '19', '20']
rating = ['100', '90', '100', '80']

dictionary = dict(zip(names, zip(id, rating)))

print(dictionary)
```

same code with unique names now outputs

```
{'bob': ('15', '100'), 'john': ('19', '100'), 'sally': ('12', '90'), 'jill': ('20', '80')}
```

What can I do better than "dict(zip(names, zip(id, rating)))"  so I can repeat 'bob' as much as I want?

Comment: you can't repeat keys in a dict, that's the whole point

Comment: I believe this is because dictionaries are expected to have a non-repetitive key, otherwise it's impossible to discriminate which value is needed when calling a key that's repeated in the dictionary. Your key should be `id` and not `name` in this scenario.

Comment: oooh, thank you! Sorry, I'm learning.  my "id" will always be unique, so I'll make that be the key instead.

Comment: [Does this post help?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10664856/make-a-dictionary-with-duplicate-keys-in-python)

Answer (score 0):

Well, unfortunately, you can't use the same key for different values in a dictionary; that would mean that each key would have a different value, which would break the main idea. What I would do instead, if you must have repeating keys, is to change the name according to its position in the original list.

```py
names = ['bob', 'bob', 'bob', 'bob']
id = ['15', '12', '19', '20']
rating = ['100', '90', '100', '80']

new_dict = {}
for i in range(len(names)):
    new_dict[f'{names[i]} #{i}'] = (id[i], rating[i])
```

You will get a dict consisting of the names in `names` and their relative positions. This will result in a `ListIndex` error if you have `id` or `rating` shorter than `names`.

Answer (score 0):

you can try this:

```
a={}
b=[]
for n,i,r in zip(names,id,rating):
  a[n] = (i,r)
  b.append(a)
```

This will return you a list of dictionary
output:

```
[{'bob': ('20', '80')},
 {'bob': ('20', '80')},
 {'bob': ('20', '80')},
 {'bob': ('20', '80')}]
```