# Switching key:value list to have values as keys?

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a CSV where the data is structured like so:

> Key |  Value
>    A   | 1, 2, 3
>    B   | 4, 5
>    C   | 1, 3, 5

I want to convert it into a CSV that looks like this:

> Key |  Value
>    1   | A, C
>    2   | A
>    3   | A, C
>    4   | B
>    5   | B, C

The current values are strings (not numbers) separated by commas. The keys are not unique - a key can appear multiple times, with different values. I've only done this previously where there was one value per line, not multiple.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Make a dictionary with duplicate keys in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10664856/make-a-dictionary-with-duplicate-keys-in-python)

Comment: If the file actually delimits the leftmost column with the vertical pipe symbol `|` I wouldn't really call that a csv.

Comment: Apologies, I did this as a visual marker for me so as not to confuse the multiple commas - but yes, it is a csv

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that the input has been loaded into a dictionary of lists, this should work for making the conversion:

```
from collections import defaultdict

input_dict = { 'A': [1, 2, 3], 'B': [4, 5], 'C': [1, 3, 5] }
output_dict = defaultdict(list)

for k, v in input_dict.items():
    for e in v:
        output_dict[e].append(k)
```

The result is as expected:

```
output_dict
=> defaultdict(<type 'list'>, {1: ['A', 'C'], 2: ['A'], 3: ['A', 'C'], 4: ['B'], 5: ['C', 'B']})
```

Now you can write the output to a CSV file with the format you want.