# How to have an element from a dictionary of a list

Tags: python, database, list, dictionary

I'm working on a problem that I can't resolve since this morning. I tried a lot of thing but it never works.

I explain you my problem.
I have a list in python and in this list I have a dictionary , like this :

```
"links": [{"url": "http://catherineingram.com/biography.html", "type": {"key": "/type/link"}, "title": "Biography"}, {"url": "http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4lJK9cfXP3c", "type": {"key": "/type/link"}, "title": "Interview on Consciousness TV"}, {"url": "http://www.huffingtonpost.com/catherine-ingram/", "type": {"key": "/type/link"}, "title": "Blog on Huffington Post"}]
```

And my goal is to recover the 3 elements of URL and put it in my database  and I try too to recover the 3 element title and put it in my database

I tried it

```
for record in csv.DictReader(open(INPUT_FILE, 'r'), fieldnames=COLUMNS, delimiter='\t'):
    j = json.loads(record['json'])

    if 'links' in j:
        for n in j['links']:
            lien.append(n)
        print(lien)
        dico = {"url": lien[(0)]}
        print(dico)

    else:
        links= ''
```

Here input file here ties in the links that I give you above.

So I would like to know How can I got only "url" and "title" from my links

The results about what I did( my code that I show you )  is :

```
[{'url': 'http://catherineingram.com/biography.html', 'type': {'key': '/type/link'}, 'title': 'Biography'}, {'url': 'http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4lJK9cfXP3c', 'type': {'key': '/type/link'}, 'title': 'Interview on Consciousness TV'}, {'url': 'http://www.huffingtonpost.com/catherine-ingram/', 'type': {'key': '/type/link'}, 'title': 'Blog on Huffington Post'}]
{'url': {'url': 'http://catherineingram.com/biography.html', 'type': {'key': '/type/link'}, 'title': 'Biography'}}
```

And I would like to have only these element  :

```
'url': 'http://catherineingram.com/biography.html'
'title': 'Biography'
'url': 'http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4lJK9cfXP3c'
'title': 'Interview on Consciousness TV'
'url': 'http://www.huffingtonpost.com/catherine-ingram/'
'title': 'Blog on Huffington Post'
```

Answer (score 2):

```
result = []
for record in csv.DictReader(open(INPUT_FILE, 'r'), fieldnames=COLUMNS, delimiter='\t'):
j = json.loads(record['json'])

if 'links' in j:
    for link in j['links']:
        result.append(link['url'])
        result.append(link['title'])
else:
    links= ''
```

You just have to access the attribut of the current array element.

The output you desire is quit weird, you want a dictionary or a simple array ?

So if you want to reconstruct a dictionary just have to follow this code :

```
result = []
for record in csv.DictReader(open(INPUT_FILE, 'r'), fieldnames=COLUMNS, delimiter='\t'):
j = json.loads(record['json'])

if 'links' in j:
    for link in j['links']:
        result.append({ 'url': link['url'], 'title': link['title']})
else:
    links= ''
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if I really understand your problem, but if you just want to have the url and title, you can drop the "type" key, and have the rest :

```
for item in j['links']:
    item.pop('type', None)
```

Answer (score 0):

The elements in your desired dictionary have duplicate keys. Python doesn't support this, and although [there are ways around this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10664876/10763533), it doesn't give you the result you have asked for.

It would instead give the following:

```py
{
    "url": [
        "http://catherineingram.com/biography.html",
        "http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4lJK9cfXP3c",
        "http://www.huffingtonpost.com/catherine-ingram/",
    ],
    "title": ["Biography", "Interview on Consciousness TV", "Blog on Huffington Post"],
}
```

However, if you wanted to print the results, then it would be straightforward:

```py
# Original results
results = [{'url': 'http://catherineingram.com/biography.html',
  'type': {'key': '/type/link'},
  'title': 'Biography'},
 {'url': 'http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4lJK9cfXP3c',
  'type': {'key': '/type/link'},
  'title': 'Interview on Consciousness TV'},
 {'url': 'http://www.huffingtonpost.com/catherine-ingram/',
  'type': {'key': '/type/link'},
  'title': 'Blog on Huffington Post'}]

# Each item in the list is a dictionary
for dict in results:
    for item in dict:
        # We only want urls and titles
        if item != 'type':
            print(f"{item}: {dict[item]}")

# OUTPUT
# url: http://catherineingram.com/biography.html
# title: Biography
# url: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4lJK9cfXP3c
# title: Interview on Consciousness TV
# url: http://www.huffingtonpost.com/catherine-ingram/
# title: Blog on Huffington Post
```

Answer (score 0):

@harens Thanks for your answer, I tried your method and I got it :

```
[{'url': 'http://catherineingram.com/biography.html', 'type': {'key': '/type/link'}, 'title': 'Biography'}, {'url': 'http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4lJK9cfXP3c', 'type': {'key': '/type/link'}, 'title': 'Interview on Consciousness TV'}, {'url': 'http://www.huffingtonpost.com/catherine-ingram/', 'type': {'key': '/type/link'}, 'title': 'Blog on Huffington Post'}]
```

So I got type yet but when I want put it in my database, it did nothing :

@AntoineFrau

I tried too your method and I got it :

```
[{'url': 'http://catherineingram.com/biography.html', 'title': 'Biography'}, {'url': 'http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4lJK9cfXP3c', 'title': 'Interview on Consciousness TV'}, {'url': 'http://www.huffingtonpost.com/catherine-ingram/', 'title': 'Blog on Huffington Post'}]
```

So it works perfectely but my problem  is that, when I try to put it in my database like this :

```
result=[]

    if 'links' in j:
        for link in j['links']:
            result.append({'url': link['url'], 'title': link['title']})
        print(result)
        links=result
    else:
        links = ''

         #   print(n)
            #links_url.append(n['url'])
            #links_title.append(n['title'])
            # links_url.append(n['url'])
            # links_title.append(n['title'])



    c.execute('INSERT INTO AUTHORS VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)',
          [record['key'],
           j.get('name'),
           j.get('eastern_order'),
           j.get('personal_name'),
           j.get('enumeration'),
           j.get('title'),
           bio,
           alternate_names,
           uris,
           j.get('location'),
           j.get('birth_date'),
           j.get('death_date'),
           j.get('date'),
           j.get('wikipedia'),
           links
          ])
db.commit()
```

It gives me an error about links :

```
 line 63, in <module>
    c.execute('INSERT INTO AUTHORS VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)',
sqlite3.InterfaceError: Error binding parameter 14 - probably unsupported type.
```

I try to put url and title in my database in the entity "links"

Thanks for your answer again !