# print() all the items of a dictionary, Python 3.8.2

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm new in Python and I'm trying to print a dictionary that I made:

```python
print({
    "Mamifero":"Gato", 
    "Reptil":"Lagartija", 
    "Mamifero":"Perro", 
    "Reptil":"Tortuga", 
    "Reptil":"Serpiente", 
    "Mamifero":"Koala"
})
```

But the Windows console only gave me this:

`{'Mamifero': 'Koala', 'Reptil': 'Serpiente'}`

How do I do to see all the elements using print()?

Comment: You have duplicate keys in your dictionary, they have to be unique or their previous key-value association will get overwritten.

Comment: That *is* all the elements. What were you expecting to see, and why?

Comment: Your problem is in the unique keys dictionary, read the official python documentation for more details. [https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3VKEr.png)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the function `.items()`, this returns the `key` and `value` in a `list` of `tuples`. But first define your dictionary.

Example:

```
dic =   {'a' : 1, 'b' : 2, 'c' : 3 , 'd' : 4}
print(dic.items())
```

Answer (score 1):

Your problem actually bypassing the need for unique keys in the dictionary. 
As discussed in the thread [Make a dictionary with duplicate keys in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10664856/make-a-dictionary-with-duplicate-keys-in-python),
the most convenient solution might be in creating custom class as following:

```
class p(object):
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
    def __repr__(self):
        return self.name
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

d = {p('Mamifero'): 'Gato', p('Reptil'): 'Lagartija', p('Mamifero'): 'Perro', p('Reptil'): 'Tortuga', p('Reptil'): 'Serpiente', p('Mamifero'): 'Koala'}

print(d)
```

Otherwise, the thread provides many similar solutions. This might be the easiest to reproduce, though.

Answer (score 0):

First, a dictionary should have distinct keys. After you fix that, I suggest you check out dictionaries' functionalities below:

Input:

```
# First_Name: [age, job, eyes]
peoples_details = {
    "Tom":[25, "Lawyer", "Brown"], 
    "Adam":[28, "Python Specialist", "Blue"], 
    "John":[45, "Unemployed", "Green"] 
}

for value in peoples_details.values():
    print(value)

for you_can_name_this_var_anything_actually in peoples_details.keys():
    print(you_can_name_this_var_anything_actually)

for key, value in peoples_details.items():
    print(key, value)
```

Output:

```
====================== RESTART: C:/Users/tom/Desktop/py.py =====================
[25, 'Lawyer', 'Brown']
[28, 'Python Specialist', 'Blue']
[45, 'Unemployed', 'Green']
Tom
Adam
John
Tom [25, 'Lawyer', 'Brown']
Adam [28, 'Python Specialist', 'Blue']
John [45, 'Unemployed', 'Green']
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everyone, I'm learn something today and I create this as an example of a Dictionary:

```
dictionary_1 = {"animal":"gato", "numero_patas":4, "cola":True, "edad":3.6, "nombre":None}
print(dictionary_1)

for key, value in dictionary_1.items():
    print(key, "=", value)
```

And the Windows Console gave me this:

```
{'animal': 'gato', 'numero_patas': 4, 'cola': True, 'edad': 3.6, 'nombre': None}

animal = gato
numero_patas = 4
cola = True
edad = 3.6
nombre = None
```

Thank you very much.