# Convert list to a dictionary with list of values for a duplicate key in Python

Tags: python, dictionary

I want to convert list to a dictionary that will have duplicate keys so to have all values I would like to have a list of values within a dict.

input as list:

```
l = ['a', '1', 'b', '2', 'a', '3']
```

Output should look like this:

```
d = {'a': ['1','3'], 'b': '2' }
```

Comment: And what defines what a key or a value is? Please be more specific

Comment: are letters always the keys?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10664856/make-a-dictionary-with-duplicate-keys-in-python You can refer this

Comment: each pair in the list is a key and a value.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
res = {}
for i in range(0, len(l), 2):
    res.setdefault(l[i], []).append(l[i+1])
print(res)
```

**Output:**

```
{'a': ['1', '3'], 'b': ['2']}
```

You can also use `zip()`

```
res = {}
for k, v in zip(l[0::2], l[1::2]):
    res.setdefault(k, []).append(v)
```

Comment: why the step of 2?

Comment: because each pair of elements considered as key and value

Comment: ooh, makes sense

Comment: Thanks, @deadshot, you rock, I have been struggling with this but you made it so easy for me.

Answer (score 0):

```
from collections import defaultdict

d = defaultdict(list)
l = ['a', '1', 'b', '2', 'a', '3']
for idx,x in enumerate(l):
    if idx % 2 != 0:
        d[l[idx-1]].append(x)
print(d)
```

output

```
defaultdict(<class 'list'>, {'a': ['1', '3'], 'b': ['2']})
```