# Combine dicts with "duplicate" keys from list

Tags: python

I receive data from an internal interface that comes as a list of dicts where **multiple** of those dicts represent a data-record if they where combined.

Data looks similar to this:

```
# received data contains 'duplicate' dict-keys
DATA = [
    {"ID": 1234},
    {"PRICE": 77.33},
    {"DATE": "20201222"},
    {"ID": 4567},
    {"PRICE": 100.99},
    {"DATE": "20201222"}
]
```

In the above example, a "complete" record would contain the dicts `ID`, `PRICE` and `DATE`.

Unfortunately the dict-keys exists multiple times so when I try something like this:

```
result = {}
for row in DATA:
    for idx, val in row.items():
        result[idx] = val

print(result)
# {
#     'ID': 4567,
#     'PRICE': 100.99,
#     'DATE': '20201222'
# }
```

The dict-keys (obviously) overwrite themselves.

I can't find a solution on how to combine the data into this desired structure:

```
DESIRED = [
    {
        "ID": 1234,
        "PRICE": 77.33,
        "DATE": "20201222"
    },
    {
        "ID": 4567,
        "PRICE": 100.99,
        "DATE": "20201222"
    }
]
```

Any hints for this? I'm even unsure on how to search for a solution to be honest.

Comment: will it always come in triplets?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the values are always contiguous (and of size 3), you could use [zip](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip) to iterate in triplets:

```
DATA = [
    {"ID": 1234},
    {"PRICE": 77.33},
    {"DATE": "20201222"},
    {"ID": 4567},
    {"PRICE": 100.99},
    {"DATE": "20201222"}
]


res = [{**i, **price, **date } for i, price, date in zip(DATA[::3], DATA[1::3], DATA[2::3])]
print(res)
```

**Output**

```
[{'DATE': '20201222', 'ID': 1234, 'PRICE': 77.33},
 {'DATE': '20201222', 'ID': 4567, 'PRICE': 100.99}]
```

An alternative solution is to use, the following *for* loop:

```
res = []
for i, price, date in zip(DATA[::3], DATA[1::3], DATA[2::3]):
    res.append({"ID": i["ID"], "PRICE": price["PRICE"], "DATE": date["DATE"]})
```

Comment: Dani this is nothing short of amazing! Thanks a lot, it works like a charm! :-)

Answer (score 0):

If your `DATA` dictionaries are guaranteed to appear in the order you've shown, and they always appear in groups of three, you can grab three dictionaries at a time and merge them:

```
from itertools import islice

data = iter([
    {"ID": 1234},
    {"PRICE": 77.33},
    {"DATE": "20201222"},
    {"ID": 4567},
    {"PRICE": 100.99},
    {"DATE": "20201222"}
])

while chunk := list(islice(data, 3)):
    id_dict, price_dict, date_dict = chunk
    merged = {**id_dict, **price_dict, **date_dict}
    print(merged)
```

Output:

```
{'ID': 1234, 'PRICE': 77.33, 'DATE': '20201222'}
{'ID': 4567, 'PRICE': 100.99, 'DATE': '20201222'}
>>>
```

Answer (score 0):

They might be a better way to do it but a simple loop with a step of 3 is sufficient.
As long as the input data is formatted as you showed it will work.
For example:

```
DATA = [
    {"ID": 1234},
    {"PRICE": 77.33},
    {"DATE": "20201222"},
    {"ID": 4567},
    {"PRICE": 100.99},
    {"DATE": "20201222"}
]

DESIRED = []

for i in range(0,len(DATA),3):
    DESIRED.append(DATA[i]) #ID
    DESIRED[-1].update(DATA[i+1]) #PRICE
    DESIRED[-1].update(DATA[i+2]) #DATE

print(DESIRED)
```

Answer (score 0):

Dictionaries do not support duplicate keys. The alternative solution is to create keys with a list of values. This can be done in two different ways:

Using setdefault method: please refer to this link [Make a dictionary with duplicate keys in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10664856/make-a-dictionary-with-duplicate-keys-in-python)!

```
results = {}   
for i, dict in enumerate(DATA):
    for k,v in DATA[i].items():
        results.setdefault(k, []).append(v)
print(results)
```

Using defaultdict method: please refer to this link [Make a dictionary with duplicate keys in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10664856/make-a-dictionary-with-duplicate-keys-in-python)!

```
from collections import defaultdict
default_dict = defaultdict(list)

for i, dict in enumerate(DATA):
    for k,v in DATA[i].items():
        default_dict[k].append(v)
print(default_dict)
```

Answer (score 0):

if you are looking for an approach which is flexible and can handle any size of data with any names then here it is:

```
items = {}

DATA = [
    {"ID": 1234},
    {"PRICE": 77.33},
    {"DATE": "20201222"},
    {"ID": 4567},
    {"PRICE": 100.99},
    {"DATE": "20201222"}
]

for i in DATA:
    key = list(i.keys())[0]
    val = i[key]
    if key in items:
        items[key].append(val)
    else:
        items[key] = [val]

output = []
keys = list(items.keys())
values = list(items.values())

for i in range(len(values[0])):
    curData = {}
    for k in keys:
        curData[k] = items[k][i]
    output.append(curData)

for i in output:
    print(i)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a nested dictionary comprehension:

```
data = [{'ID': 1234}, {'PRICE': 77.33}, {'DATE': '20201222'}, {'ID': 4567}, {'PRICE': 100.99}, {'DATE': '20201222'}]
r = [{a:b for j in data[i:i+3] for a, b in j.items()} for i in range(0, len(data), 3)]
```

Output:

```
[{'ID': 1234, 'PRICE': 77.33, 'DATE': '20201222'}, {'ID': 4567, 'PRICE': 100.99, 'DATE': '20201222'}]
```