# Getting maximum value of each key in Python?

Tags: python, loops, dictionary, hashmap, key

I'm working on a problem in which I have one dictionary, but there exist duplicate keys within it. The goal is to get the maximum value of each corresponding key, but I am confused about how to do this because the previous examples I've seen show how to get the maximum value from the dictionary as a whole. Is there a way to compare one key with the rest of the keys, see if it is a match, and then examine their values? This is what I have tried so far:

```
# Create mock dictionary with data
gene_data = {'geneA': 1, 
    'geneB': 2, 
    'geneC': 0,
    'geneA': 3,
    'geneB': 1,
    'geneC': 4
}

# Pass in your dictionary as the parameter.
# Return a newly created dictionary that displays each key once, alongside the maximum value.
# For our example, our expected outcome is:
# new_dict = {'geneA': 3, 'geneB': 2, 'geneC': 4}
def get_max_value_from_data(data):
    new_dict = dict()
    for key, value in data.items():
        for i in range(0, len(data)):
            if key == data.keys()[i]:
                if value < data.values()[i]:
                    new_dict[key] = value
    return new_dict
    
get_max_value_from_data(gene_data)
```

Comment: Dictionaries have unique keys

Comment: Duplicate keys are not allowed.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10664856/make-a-dictionary-with-duplicate-keys-in-python Duplicate keys not allowed here workaround

Comment: https://www.google.com/amp/s/www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-find-keys-with-duplicate-values-in-dictionary/amp/ Use this and rename duplicate like gene-a gene-a-2 and so on