# How to assign dictionary of dictionary to a variable in robot file

Tags: python, rest, robotframework

I have a variable &{userList} and I've assigned the below value to it:

```
&{userList}                 id={rand_id}    extension={rand_extn}
```

Then I am replacing the {rand_id} and {rand_extn} in my test case as:

```
${uni_id}=    Generate Random String    2    [NUMBERS]
${uni_extn}=    Generate Random String    4    [NUMBERS]
: FOR    ${key}    IN    @{userList.keys()}
\    ${updated_val}=    Replace String    ${userList["${key}"]}    {rand_id}    ${uni_id}
\    Set To Dictionary    ${userList}    ${key}    ${updated_val}
\    ${updated_val}=    Replace String    ${userList["${key}"]}    {rand_extn}    ${uni_extn}
\    Set To Dictionary    ${userList}    ${key}    ${updated_val}
```

Now I wanted to create one variable which can have nested dictionary but I don't know how to do this. I am doing like this:

```
&{multipleUserList}         id={rand_id}    extension={rand_extn},  id={rand_id2}    extension={rand_extn2}
```

And then I wanted to replace the values like this:

```
${uni_id}=    Generate Random String    2    [NUMBERS]
${uni_extn}=    Generate Random String    4    [NUMBERS]
${uni_id2}=    Generate Random String    2    [NUMBERS]
${uni_extn2}=    Generate Random String    4    [NUMBERS]
: FOR    ${key}    IN    @{multipleUserList.keys()}
\    ${updated_val1}=    Replace String    ${multipleUserList["${key}"]}    {rand_id}    ${uni_id}
\    Set To Dictionary    ${multipleUserList}    ${key}    ${updated_val1}
\    ${updated_val2}=    Replace String    ${multipleUserList["${key}"]}    {rand_extn}    ${uni_extn}
\    Set To Dictionary    ${multipleUserList}    ${key}    ${updated_val2}
\    ${updated_val3}=    Replace String    ${multipleUserList["${key}"]}    {rand_id2}    ${uni_id2}
\    Set To Dictionary    ${multipleUserList}    ${key}    ${updated_val3}
\    ${updated_val4}=    Replace String    ${multipleUserList["${key}"]}    {rand_extn2}    ${uni_extn2}
\    Set To Dictionary    ${multipleUserList}    ${key}    ${updated_val4}
```

When I am running this and printing the values of ${multipleUserList}, I am getting values from ${uni_id2} and ${uni_extn2} but values of ${uni_id} and ${uni_extn} are not coming:

```
{u'id': u'60', u'extension': u'4858'}
```

Kindly help me in getting all the values. I am creating a body of the REST API when I've to create multiple user.

Answer (score 0):

You can do your dictionary merge directly in python :
https://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/libraries/BuiltIn.html#Evaluate

Answer (score 0):

Dictionaries can have only unique keys normally. You can take a look [at this old discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10664856/make-a-dictionary-with-duplicate-keys-in-python) - Since Robot is basically just a layer on top of Python, same rules apply here. You are attempting to assign key `id` and key `extension` multiple times with different values. What that does, is to update the existing keys with the new values - Instead of adding new keys.

In Robot there's a keyword in `Set To Dictionary` the [Collections Library](https://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/libraries/Collections.html#Set%20To%20Dictionary) which can be used to add multiple key-value pairs to an existing dictionary.

Just as an example, following would achieve the situation where you have 2 unique Id keys and 2 unique extension keys within the same dictionary. This way they are not overridden during the execution.

```
Set to Dictionary    ${multipleUserList}    id-1=${rand_id}    extension-1=${rand_extn}    
...                  id-2=${rand_id2}    extension-2=${rand_extn2}
```

Notice that the dictionary is used with `$` instead of `&`.

Also wanted to point out, your current dictionary generation system does not maintain the connection between `id` and `extension` values. Dictionaries are not ordered so if the connection of the values is important, some other organizing method should be considered.