# Does python dictionary have duplicate keys?

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary

I am trying to create a python dictiory with dupliate key as follows.

```
x = {"a" :1,"b":2,"z": 4, "c":90, "z":0, "k":None}
print(x["z"])
```

when i am calling key `"z"` value it is printing `0` why it is not printing `4`? does it valid to have duplicat keys in dictionary?

Comment: What exactly are you asking? The code already demonstrates that there is only one value per key and that it is the last one assigned.

Comment: *"I am trying to create a python dictiory with dupliate key"* - and why would you do that?

Comment: Please search before creating a post.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Make a dictionary with duplicate keys in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10664856/make-a-dictionary-with-duplicate-keys-in-python)

Answer (score 0):

Keys within a dictionary in python are unique, therefore you cannot have duplicate keys. The reason you are getting "0" is that when you define "z" the second time in your dictionary, this key/value pair is overwriting your original pair.

Answer (score 0):

Python dictionary does not supports multiple key.
You can store multiple values on one key using a list.
Something like:

```
dictionary = {
'a' : 1,
'z': [0, 4]
}
```