# How to add new values to a value of dictionary in python

Tags: python

I want to add a value to a dictionary as the follow:

```
dic = {'key1': {1: 1},
         'key2': {2: 5, 1: 1},
         'key3': {2: 2, 1: 2},

 }
```

Want to add a value for "key1" => **{3:4, 1:5}**

Expected output:

```
dic = {'key1': {1: 1, 3:4, 1:5},
         'key2': {2: 5, 1: 1},
         'key3': {2: 2, 1: 2},

 }
```

I tried this but it's not giving me the required output.

```
dict[key1].append(value)
```

Would you please help? Thank you in advance!!

Comment: Dictionary keys must be unique. You cannot have `1` be a key in the same dictionary twice, the second value will overwrite the first.

Comment: Please show us what `value` is. Also, dictionaries do not have `append`.

Comment: I want to add {3:4, 1:5} to the existing value of key1. That will be =>   'key1': {1: 1, 3:4, 1:5}

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Make a dictionary with duplicate keys in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10664856/make-a-dictionary-with-duplicate-keys-in-python)

Answer (score 0):

The function you are looking for is `dict.update()`. However, as was pointed out in the comments, duplicate keys will be silently overwritten.

e.g.

```
dic["key1"].update({3: 4, 1: 5})
```

edit:

On the subject of duplicate keys, this SO question provides multiple ways to create a similar behavior: [Make a dictionary with duplicate keys in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10664856/make-a-dictionary-with-duplicate-keys-in-python)

Answer (score 0):

In Python 3.5 and later, we can expand a dictionary into another dictionary with:

```
a = {4: 5}
b = {**a}
```

If we do this with two dictionaries, we get a merging of them, but with values in the second overwriting values for the same keys in the first.

```
a = {4: 5}
b = {1: 2, 4: 7}
c = {**a, **b}
```

`c` will now be `{4: 7, 1: 2}`

So you might write:

```
dict[key1] = {**dict[key1], **{3: 4, 1: 5}}
```

Answer (score 0):

`append()` is a method on the builtin `list` type. Since the value associated with `key1` is the builtin `dict` type, you won't be able to use `append()` to achieve this. There is another issue pertaining to your expected output:

```py
{
    1: 1,
    3: 4,
    1: 5,
}
```

You have two values for the key `1` in this dictionary. In python dictionaries, you can only have a single key. If you wanted to have multiple values for a particular key, there's a few ways to handle this (I would recommend reading up on [Hash Tables: Collision Resolution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table#Collision_resolution)).

For this example, given you were trying to use the `append()` method, I'm going to assume you wanted to update the value stored to be a list containing `[1, 5]`. In this case, one way of solving this would be with the following code.

```py
dic = {
    'key1': {1: 1},
    'key2': {2: 5, 1: 1},
    'key3': {2: 2, 1: 2},
 }

key1_new_dict = {
    1: [5],
    3: [4],
}

for key, value in dic['key1'].items():
    if key in key1_new_dict:
        key1_new_dict[key].append(value)
    else:
        key1_new_dict[key] = [value]
```