# How to remove duplicate values from a list which are the values in the dictionary?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, dictionary, defaultdict

I made a dictionary subclass that will store duplicated values in lists under the same key automatically from reference to

[Make a dictionary with duplicate keys in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10664856/make-a-dictionary-with-duplicate-keys-in-python)

```
class Dictlist(dict):
    def __setitem__(self, key, value):
        try:
            self[key]
        except KeyError:
            super(Dictlist, self).__setitem__(key, [])
        self[key].append(value)

d = Dictlist()

d['test'] = 1
d['test'] = 2
d['test'] = 1
d['test'] = 1

print(d)
{'test' : [1,2,1,1]}
for k,v in d.items():
    d[k] = list(set(v))

print(d)
{'test': [1, 2, 1, 1, [1, 2]]}
```

In this case, the new list is being added to the values list. I just want `[1,2]` in the values.

Comment: why not use a defaultdict instead of a custom class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've overriden `__setitem__`, so the line `d[k] = list(set(v))` will call the override and append to the list. In order to set the key directly, you need to bypass the override and access the method in `dict`.

One way to do this would be to provide a method in `Dictlist`. For instance:

```python3
def set_item(self, key, value):
    super().__setitem__(key, value)
```

and then call `d.set_item(k, list(set(v)))`.

If this uniquification is the only operation you need to perform on the dictionary that uses this bypass, you could put all the logic in one method of `Dictlist`:

```python3
def uniquify(self):
    for key in self.keys():
        super().__setitem__(key, list(set(self[key])))
```

If for whatever reason you can't modify `Dictlist`, you can bypass from outside the class as follows:

```python3
dict.__setitem__(d, k, list(set(v)))
```