# create dict from different list with first element

Tags: python, arrays, list, sorting, dictionary

I have this data:

```
[1999, teacher, 5]
[1999, student, 6]
[2000, doctor, 11]
```

I want to create dict:

```
{'1999': {'field1': teacher, 'field2': 5}, '2000': {'field1': doctor, 'field2': 11}}
```

How can I get 2 unique years from data and set it in dict?Please can anybody help to understand

Comment: What happened to `[1999, student, 6]`?

Comment: Why are you using a dict for this purpose?

Comment: I sorted it from array by loop

Comment: I get the unique year requirement, but why `teacher` for `field1` and not `student`. why does teacher/5 win over student/6? Is the sort on field2, where the min(field2) for each distinct year is the winner?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Make a dictionary with duplicate keys in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10664856/make-a-dictionary-with-duplicate-keys-in-python)

Comment: Why create keys that have no meaning? `"field1"` has no meaning therefore just using a list would make more sense with this context.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

we dont know the format of the data you are having.

if you have list of lists:

```py
data = [[1999, 'teacher', 5], [1999, 'student', 6], [2000, 'doctor', 11]]

res = {}
for record in data:
    res[str(record[0])] = {f'field{k}': v for k, v in enumerate(record[1:], start=1)}
```

if you have text (or file):

```py
import io

data = io.StringIO('''[1999, teacher, 5]
[1999, student, 6]
[2000, doctor, 11]''')
res = {}
for line in data.readlines():
    record = line.replace('[', '').replace(']', '').split(',')
    res[record[0]] = {f'field{k}': v.strip() for k, v in enumerate(record[1:], start=1)}
```

Answer (score 0):

How about using Python's iterators, this is pure beauty:

```
data = [[1999, 'teacher', 5], [1999, 'student', 6], [2000, 'doctor', 11]]
print({str(next(obj)): {'field1': next(obj), 'field2': next(obj)} for obj in map(iter, data)})
```

**Output:**

```
{'1999': {'field1': 'student', 'field2': 6}, '2000': {'field1': 'doctor', 'field2': 11}}
```