# Missing item when performing a "for" loop

Tags: python, dictionary, for-loop

I have a dictionary that has English words as keys and Finnish words as values. I'm trying to make a function to reverse this dictionary.

For example:

```
dictionary = {'move':['liikutta'], 'six':['kuusi'], 'fir':['kuusi']}
```

Expected output:

```
reverse = {'liikutta':['move'], 'kuusi':['six'], 'kuusi':['fir']}
```

The codes I'm using:

```
    def reverse_dictionary(dictionary):
    reverse = {}
    for key, value in dictionary.items():
         for i in range(len(value)):
             reverse.update({value[i]:[key]})
    return reverse
```

The 2nd item in the dictionary was skipped. I guess it was because the repeated 'kuusi', but I don't know how to solve it.

Output

```
{'liikutta':['move'], 'kuusi':['fir']}
```

Thanks all!

Comment: Dict cannot have duplicate keys, check [`link`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10664876/4985099)

Comment: You can't solve it. Keys in dictionary must be unique. https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries
You probably need a different data type.
What do you think about this output: `{'liikutta':['move'], 'kuusi':['fir', "six"]}`

Comment: Modified: Is there any way to group 'six' and 'fir' into 'kuusi'. Like this: `{'liikutta':['move'], 'kuusi':['six', 'fir']}`

Answer (score 0):

Every key in a dictionary has to be unique.
What you can do, is update the list.

```
dictionary = {'move': ['liikutta'], 'six': ['kuusi'], 'fir': ['kuusi']}


def reverse_dictionary(dictionary):
    reverse = dict()
    for key, value in dictionary.items():
        l = reverse.get(value[0], [])  # get the list or an empty list
        l.append(key)  # append the key
        reverse.update({value[0]: l})  # update the dictionary
    return reverse

reverse_dictionary(dictionary)
```

output:

```
{'liikutta': ['move'], 'kuusi': ['six', 'fir']}
```

In one line:

```
reverse.update({value[0]: reverse.get(value[0], []) + [key]})
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use a list as a value - as it is in the original dictionary - then you can do it like this.

```
from collections import defaultdict


def reverse_dictionary(dictionary):
    reverse = defaultdict(list)
    for key, values in dictionary.items():
        for value in values:
            reverse[value].append(key)
    return reverse


dictionary = {'move': ['liikutta'], 'six': ['kuusi'], 'fir': ['kuusi']}
print(reverse_dictionary(dictionary))
```

The result is `defaultdict(<class 'list'>, {'liikutta': ['move'], 'kuusi': ['six', 'fir']})`.

A [`defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) behaves like a normal dictionary, but it calls a factory function to supply missing values. In this case it's a `list`.

Answer (score 0):

The straight and simple answer is NO. You can't have duplicate keys in a dictionary in Python, the keys should be unique in, And if you attempt to do so,it will just overwrite the previous value of the key.But you can have multiple values associated to a key

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```
dictionary = {'move':['liikutta'], 'six':['kuusi'], 'fir':['kuusi']}
reverse = {}
for key, value in dictionary.items():
    for i in value:

        if i in reverse.keys():
            reverse[i].append(key)
        else:
            reverse[i]=[key]
print(reverse)
```

Result:

```
{'liikutta': ['move'], 'kuusi': ['six', 'fir']}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
def revd(d):
    r = {}
    for k,v in d.items():
        for i in v:
            # below is ternary expression, it updates r 
            r[i].append(k) if i in r else r.setdefault(i,[k])
    return r
```

Side remark: Instead of

```
for i in range(len(value)):
```

use

```
for i, v in enumerate(value))
```