# How can I print the values of duplicate keys in a dictionary?

Tags: python, dictionary, duplicates, key

It's only printing the last key, value pair in the Nested titles.

Here's the code I am using:

```
def displayAllTabs(dict_items):

for dict in dict_items:
    
    title = dict.get("Title")
    print(title)

    if "NestedTabs" in dict.keys():

        nestedTitle = dict["NestedTabs"]["Title"]
        print(f'\t{nestedTitle}')
```

Here's my list:

```
[
    {
        "index": 1,
        "Title": "SE Factory",
        "Url": "https://www.sefactory.io",
        "NestedTabs": {"Title": "UI", "Url": "https://www.sefactory.io/uix"},
    },
    {"index": 2, "Title": "Google", "Url": "https://www.google.com"},
    {
        "index": 3,
        "Title": "W3schools",
        "Url": "https://www.w3schools.com",
        "NestedTabs": {
            "Title": "Html",
            "Url": "https://www.w3schools.com/html/default.asp",
            "Title": "Css",
            "Url": "https://www.w3schools.com/css/default.asp",
            "Title": "JavaScript",
            "Url": "https://www.w3schools.com/js/default.asp",
        },
    },
]
```

for ex: in the w3schools nested tabs, its only printing the Javascript Title.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can one make a dictionary with duplicate keys in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10664856/how-can-one-make-a-dictionary-with-duplicate-keys-in-python)

Comment: Your dictionary doesn't have duplicate keys, because that isn't possible. When you write something like `d = {'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'a': 3}`, the last occurrence of each key simply overwrites the previous ones.

Comment: Yes, I know that the last key overwrites the previous ones. But I was asking if there's is a way to loop around this problem for printing purposes only

Comment: It's not possible, because the `dict_items` object doesn't contain any information about the "previous" values that were overwritten.

Comment: Your list (as shown in the question) is valid Python code. However, if you print the list you'll notice that it doesn't contain what you were hoping for. The values associated with NestedTabs should probably be a list of dictionaries

Answer (score -1):

Try using this solution

```
def displayAllTabs(dict_items):
    for item in dict_items:
        title = item.get("Title")
        print(title)

        if "NestedTabs" in item:
            nested_tabs = item['NestedTabs']
            if "Title" in nested_tabs and "Url" in nested_tabs:
                nested_title = nested_tabs["Title"]
                nested_url = nested_tabs["Url"]
                print(f'\tNested Tab: {nested_title} ({nested_url})')
            elif isinstance(nested_tabs, list):
                for nested_tab in nested_tabs:
                    nested_title = nested_tab.get("Title")
                    nested_url = nested_tab.get("Url")
                    print(f'\tNested Tab: {nested_title} ({nested_url})')

dict_items = [
    {
        "index": 1,
        "Title": "SE Factory",
        "Url": "https://www.sefactory.io",
        "NestedTabs": [{"Title": "UI", "Url": "https://www.sefactory.io/uix"}],
    },
    {"index": 2, "Title": "Google", "Url": "https://www.google.com"},
    {
        "index": 3,
        "Title": "W3schools",
        "Url": "https://www.w3schools.com",
        "NestedTabs": [
            {"Title": "Html", "Url": "https://www.w3schools.com/html/default.asp"},
            {"Title": "Css", "Url": "https://www.w3schools.com/css/default.asp"},
            {"Title": "JavaScript", "Url": "https://www.w3schools.com/js/default.asp"},
        ],
    },
]

displayAllTabs(dict_items=dict_items)
```

You'll need to place the items of the 'NestedTabs' dictionary inside a list. I can't think of any other ways to retrieve that information without encountering an error.

Comment: It's unusual to change the data to fit the code. It's usually the other way around

Comment: Yeah sure. I just posted a solution. I can't find other ways to retrieve the data with the specific format without running into an error.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).