# Need help understanding how to extract multiple instances of the same type from an xml file to export to Excel

Tags: python, excel, xml

I have been given a python file that extracts relevant data from a xml file to be exported to an Excel file. I have it working for the most part. The xml file is one set of data to be extracted into one row in Excel.

The issue I do not know how to resolve is how to extract (potentially) multiple values of the same type. what I wrote only extract one instance.

Here is an example of what I have in the python code:

```
 elif child.tag.endswith("titleInfo"):
                if child.attrib.get("type") == "alternative":
                    alternative_title = child.find("mods:title", namespaces).text
                    record_data["Alternative Title"] = alternative_title
```

Here is the xml relevant file info (other xml files that I need to process may have 0, 1, or more alternative titles):

```
 <mods:titleInfo type="alternative">
  <mods:title>Ziemer diary</mods:title>
 </mods:titleInfo>
 <mods:titleInfo type="alternative">
  <mods:title>F.G. Ziemer Tagebuch</mods:title>
 </mods:titleInfo>
```

**When I run it only the second instance is recorded **

There are several places in these xml files that will need the same solution.

Thanks for the help!

Full python code:

```
# MODS/METS XML to XLSX Crosswalk

import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
import pandas as pd


def parse_xml(xml_file):
    # Create an ElementTree object and parse the XML file
    tree = ET.parse(xml_file)
    root = tree.getroot()

    # Define namespaces
    namespaces = {
        "mods": "http://www.loc.gov/mods/v3",
        "mets": "http://www.loc.gov/METS/"
    }

    # Extract the necessary data from the XML structure
    data = []
    for dmdSec in root.iterfind(".//mets:dmdSec", namespaces):
        record_data = {}
        mods = dmdSec.find(".//mods:mods", namespaces)

        title = mods.find(".//mods:title", namespaces)
        if title is not None:
            record_data["Title"] = title.text


        for child in mods:
            if child.tag.endswith("title"):
                record_data["Title"] = child.text
            elif child.tag.endswith("abstract"):
                record_data["Abstract"] = child.text
            elif child.tag.endswith("identifier"):
                record_data["Identifier"] = child.text
            elif child.tag.endswith("location"):
                file_link = child.find("mods:url", namespaces).text
                record_data["Path"] = file_link
            elif child.tag.endswith("typeOfResource"):
                record_data["Type of Resource"] = child.text
            elif child.tag.endswith("genre"):
                record_data["Genre"] = child.text
            elif child.tag.endswith("subject"):
                if child.find("mods:hierarchicalGeographic", namespaces) is not None:
                    hier_geo = child.find("mods:hierarchicalGeographic", namespaces)
                    country = hier_geo.find(".//mods:country", namespaces)
                    state = hier_geo.find(".//mods:state", namespaces)
                    county = hier_geo.find(".//mods:county", namespaces)
                    city = hier_geo.find(".//mods:city", namespaces)
                    if country is not None:
                        record_data["Country"] = country.text
                    if state is not None:
                        record_data["State"] = state.text
                    if county is not None:
                        record_data["County"] = county.text
                    if city is not None:
                        record_data["City"] = city.text
                # if child.find("mods:geographic", namespaces) is not None:
                #     geographic = child.find("mods:geographic", namespaces).text
                #     record_data.setdefault("Geographic", []).append(geographic)
                # elif child.find("mods:temporal", namespaces) is not None:
                #     temporal = child.find("mods:temporal", namespaces).text
                #     record_data.setdefault("Temporal", []).append(temporal)
                # elif child.find("mods:topic", namespaces) is not None:
                #     topic = child.find("mods:topic", namespaces).text
                #     record_data.setdefault("Subject", []).append(topic)
            elif child.tag.endswith("originInfo"):
                for info in child:
                    if info.tag.endswith("place"):
                        record_data["Place"] = info.find("mods:placeTerm", namespaces).text
                    elif info.tag.endswith("publisher"):
                        record_data["Publisher"] = info.text
                    elif info.tag.endswith("dateIssued"):
                        record_data["Date Issued"] = info.text
                    elif info.tag.endswith("dateCaptured"):
                        record_data["Date Captured"] = info.text
            # elif child.tag.endswith("part"):
            #     part_number = child.find(".//mods:number", namespaces).text
            #     record_data["Date Published"] = part_number
            elif child.tag.endswith("titleInfo"):
                if child.attrib.get("type") == "alternative":
                    alternative_title = child.find("mods:title", namespaces).text
                    record_data["Alternative Title"].append(alternative_title)

            elif child.tag.endswith("name"):
                if child.attrib.get("type") == "corporate":
                    corporate_name = child.find("mods:namePart", namespaces).text
                    record_data["Corporate Name"] = corporate_name
                elif child.attrib.get("type") == "personal":
                    author_name = child.find("mods:namePart", namespaces).text
                    record_data["Author"] = author_name

            # Additional fields from the provided XML structure
            elif child.tag.endswith("language"):
                language_term = child.find("mods:languageTerm", namespaces).text
                record_data["Language"] = language_term
            elif child.tag.endswith("physicalDescription"):
                form = child.find(".//mods:form", namespaces).text
                extent = child.find(".//mods:extent", namespaces).text
                record_data["Form"] = form
                record_data["Dimensions"] = extent
            elif child.tag.endswith("accessCondition"):
                record_data["Access Condition"] = child.text

        data.append(record_data)

    return data


def xml_to_excel(xml_file, excel_file):
    # Parse XML file
    data = parse_xml(xml_file)

    # Convert data to a DataFrame
    df = pd.DataFrame(data)

    # Reorder columns to have "Title" as the first column
    if "Title" in df.columns:
        columns = df.columns.tolist()
        columns.remove("Title")
        columns = ["Title"] + columns
        df = df[columns]

    # Export to Excel
    df.to_excel(excel_file, index=False)

    print(f"Data exported to {excel_file} successfully!")


# File Management
xml_file = "/Users/spaz/Documents/David/Data Scientist/Rescarta Stuff/metadata copy.xml"  # Replace with your XML file path
excel_file = "/Users/spaz/Desktop/Outputs/output.xlsx"  # Replace with desired output Excel file path

xml_to_excel(xml_file, excel_file)
```

Here is the xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<mets:mets xmlns:mets="http://www.loc.gov/METS/" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" LABEL="Tagebuch (Ziemer diary)" OBJID="witrpl00/th190530/00000001" TYPE="ResCarta Monograph Metadata v7.0" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.loc.gov/METS/ http://www.loc.gov/standards/mets/mets.xsd http://www.loc.gov/mods/v3 http://www.loc.gov/standards/mods/v3/mods-3-4.xsd http://www.loc.gov/mix/ http://www.loc.gov/standards/mix/mix02/mix02.xsd" xmlns:mix="http://www.loc.gov/mix/" xmlns:mods="http://www.loc.gov/mods/v3">
 <mets:metsHdr CREATEDATE="2019-08-14T08:11:43.647-05:00" RECORDSTATUS="COMPLETE">
  <mets:agent ROLE="CREATOR" TYPE="ORGANIZATION">
   <mets:name>ResCarta Tools</mets:name>
   <mets:note>Generated by the ResCarta Data Conversion Tool v7.0.2</mets:note>
  </mets:agent>
 </mets:metsHdr>
 <mets:dmdSec ID="DMD1">
  <mets:mdWrap MDTYPE="MODS" MIMETYPE="text/xml">
   <mets:xmlData>
    <mods:mods>
     <mods:titleInfo>
      <mods:title>Tagebuch (Ziemer diary)</mods:title>
     </mods:titleInfo>
     <mods:titleInfo type="alternative">
      <mods:title>Ziemer diary</mods:title>
     </mods:titleInfo>
     <mods:titleInfo type="alternative">
      <mods:title>F.G. Ziemer Tagebuch</mods:title>
     </mods:titleInfo>
     <mods:name type="corporate">
      <mods:namePart>Theresa Public Library</mods:namePart>
      <mods:role>
       <mods:roleTerm authority="marcrelator" type="code">own</mods:roleTerm>
       <mods:roleTerm authority="marcrelator" type="text">Owner</mods:roleTerm>
      </mods:role>
     </mods:name>
     <mods:name type="corporate">
      <mods:namePart>Theresa Historical Society</mods:namePart>
      <mods:role>
       <mods:roleTerm authority="marcrelator" type="code">own</mods:roleTerm>
       <mods:roleTerm authority="marcrelator" type="text">Owner</mods:roleTerm>
      </mods:role>
     </mods:name>
     <mods:name type="personal">
      <mods:namePart>Ziemer, Friedrich Gorg Emanuel</mods:namePart>
      <mods:role>
       <mods:roleTerm authority="marcrelator" type="code">aut</mods:roleTerm>
       <mods:roleTerm authority="marcrelator" type="text">Author</mods:roleTerm>
      </mods:role>
     </mods:name>
     <mods:typeOfResource>text</mods:typeOfResource>
     <mods:genre authority="marcgt">book</mods:genre>
     <mods:originInfo>
      <mods:dateIssued encoding="iso8601" qualifier="questionable">1930-06-21</mods:dateIssued>
      <mods:dateCaptured encoding="iso8601">2018-09-20</mods:dateCaptured>
      <mods:issuance>monographic</mods:issuance>
     </mods:originInfo>
     <mods:language>
      <mods:languageTerm authority="iso639-2b" type="code">eng</mods:languageTerm>
     </mods:language>
     <mods:language>
      <mods:languageTerm authority="iso639-2b" type="code">ger</mods:languageTerm>
     </mods:language>
     <mods:physicalDescription>
      <mods:form authority="marcform">electronic</mods:form>
      <mods:extent>8.18 x 11.61 in.</mods:extent>
      <mods:digitalOrigin>reformatted digital</mods:digitalOrigin>
     </mods:physicalDescription>
     <mods:subject>
      <mods:hierarchicalGeographic>
       <mods:country>United States</mods:country>
       <mods:state>Wisconsin</mods:state>
       <mods:county>Dodge</mods:county>
       <mods:city>Theresa</mods:city>
      </mods:hierarchicalGeographic>
     </mods:subject>
     <mods:subject authority="lctgm">
      <mods:topic>Farm life</mods:topic>
     </mods:subject>
     <mods:subject authority="lctgm">
      <mods:topic>Farmers</mods:topic>
     </mods:subject>
     <mods:subject authority="lctgm">
      <mods:topic>Almanacs</mods:topic>
     </mods:subject>
     <mods:identifier type="local">witrpl00/th190530/00000001</mods:identifier>
     <mods:location>
      <mods:url>witrpl00/th190530/00000001</mods:url>
     </mods:location>
     <mods:accessCondition type="use and reproduction">http://rightsstatements.org/vocab/InC/1.0/</mods:accessCondition>
     <mods:part order="1">
      <mods:extent unit="pages">
       <mods:start>1</mods:start>
       <mods:end>248</mods:end>
      </mods:extent>
     </mods:part>
    </mods:mods>
   </mets:xmlData>
  </mets:mdWrap>
 </mets:dmdSec>
 <mets:amdSec ID="AMD1">
```

What follows this xml code is info about each .tiff image that each represents a page in the document (about 245 pages). Each page has xml code like the following. But it was not included here due to the length. Plus I do not think it is needed for this data transfer. According to my basic instructions I just need to convert all the .tiff files to .jpeg (I did that with some tweaking of a python file I was given) then I need to export the xml file relevant data into a one row Excel file. So to answer your other question, we would need a separate column for each data type and if multiple instances of a type exits, they can either all have their own column or otherwise combine the data into one cell for that column. No second rows.

```
   <mets:file ADMID="AMD1" CHECKSUM="f5aec7b842ec762e6cbf07a6b6bb23070e7c96dd" CHECKSUMTYPE="SHA-1" ID="FID11" MIMETYPE="image/tiff" SIZE="11393570">
    <mets:FLocat LOCTYPE="URL" xlink:href="file:///./00000011.tif" xlink:type="simple"/>
   </mets:file>

  <mets:div LABEL="11" ORDER="11" TYPE="page" xlink:label="PPG11">
    <mets:fptr FILEID="FID11"/>
   </mets:div>
```

Comment: How looks like you root tag with the namespace convention? Please share a minimal working example. How looks like your import? Python have several possibilities for xml parsing. You should use `findall()`.

Comment: I added the relevant xml file info - it has more, but this is what needs to be extracted. As you can see from the code, some elements will have just one set of text data, other elements (like alternative title, or subject) have multiple entries. Thanks again!!

Comment: Not clear how your excel should be look like. Should all title incl. alternative in one column? Or would you prefer a second column with a flag Original_Title/Alternative_Title? If you have a lot of XML, maybe it's better to transfer the data to a database like sqlite instead of excel. What size have the single XML, because ElementTree load the whole xml into the memory.

Comment: Have all your xml the wrap element? Maybe your parsing project is more complex: -> The descriptive metadata section of a METS document consists of one or more <dmdSec> (Descriptive Metadata Section) elements. Each <dmdSec> element may contain a pointer to external metadata (an <mdRef> element), internally embedded metadata (within an <mdWrap> element), or both.

Comment: Thanks for your help. This seems to be getting to be too much to ask of you. I Have included some more info and data in order to try to answer your two new questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you overwrite your dictionary with the second values. Dictionaries doesn’t allow duplicate keys, what’s the case here, [compare this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10664876/20851944).

You can search with xpath, if you use `xml.etree.ElementTree` , e.g.:

`findall()` gives you a list.

```
for alternative_title in root.findall(".//*[@type='alternative']/mods:title", namespaces):
    print(alternative_title.text)
```

Output:

```
Ziemer diary
F.G. Ziemer Tagebuch
```

**Option2**:

```
from collections import defaultdict

record_data = defaultdict(list)
for child in root.iter():
    if child.tag.endswith("titleInfo"):
        if child.attrib.get("type") == "alternative":
            alternative_title = child.find("mods:title", namespaces).text
            record_data["Alternative Title"].append(alternative_title)

for key, val in record_data.items():
    print(key, val)
# Alternative Title ['Ziemer diary', 'F.G. Ziemer Tagebuch']
```

Than you can use pandas to write to Excel:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(record_data)
print(df)
# https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_excel.html
# if you have pip install openpyxl, e.g.
# df.to_excel('output.xlsx')
```

Output:

```
      Alternative Title
0          Ziemer diary
1  F.G. Ziemer Tagebuch
```

**Suggestion**
Cut you xml in pieces and collect the data:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
import pandas as pd

class MDWrap:
    def __init__(self, ns, tree):
        self.data = []
        self.columns = ["title", "Alternative titles"]
        self.root = tree
        self.ns = ns

        # Check, if mdWrap available
        try:
            self.mdwrap = self.root.find(".//mets:mdWrap", namespaces=ns)
        except:
            print("No nmWrap node available")  

        # parse title and alternative titles
        self.titleInfo = self.root.findall(".//mods:titleInfo", namespaces=ns)
        self.titles(self.ns, self.titleInfo)
        self.data.append(self.title)
        self.data.append(self.alt_titles)

        # Parse your other stuff here ...
        # ....


    def titles(self, ns, title_nodes):
        """ self.title -> string, self.alt_title -> list """
        self.alt_titles = []
        for alt_t in title_nodes:
            if alt_t.get('type'):
                self.alt_titles.append(alt_t.find('./*').text)
                #print(alt_t.get('type'), alt_t.find('./*').text)
            if len(alt_t.attrib) == 0:
                self.title = alt_t.find('./*').text
                #print("main", self.title)

    def write_excel(self, data, col, file_out):
        df = pd.DataFrame([data], columns=col)
        print(df)
        # pip install openpyxl is necessary, if you dont have this
        df.to_excel(file_out)
                   
                
if __name__ == "__main__":
    xml_file = "lib.xml"
    xlsx_out = "dmdS_data.xlsx"
    
    nsmap = {"mets": "http://www.loc.gov/METS/", "mods":"http://www.loc.gov/mods/v3"}

    for event, node in ET.iterparse(xml_file, events=['end']):
        #print(node.tag)
        if node.tag == f"{{{nsmap['mets']}}}dmdSec":
            dmdS = node
            mdW = MDWrap(nsmap, dmdS)
            node.clear()
        
    # print(mdW.title)
    # print(mdW.alt_titles)
    # print(mdW.data)

    # Write Excel if all data collected
    mdW.write_excel(mdW.data, mdW.columns, xlsx_out)
```

Output plus Excel:

```
                     title                    Alternative titles
0  Tagebuch (Ziemer diary)  [Ziemer diary, F.G. Ziemer Tagebuch]
```

Comment: Thank you so much for trying to help. I kind of see what you are trying to explain to me, but do not quite get how to implement either option based on what the current code says. I am new to this site also, so I do not see an option to now add the complete code, If I could I would ask for a quick look over and then a suggestion on how I could best proceed - then I could complete the rest. So thanks for trying! Again this is not my code and I am a newbie. I will keep trying your ideas.

Comment: OK all, I just added the full python code. I have so much to learn...

Comment: It would be help to see the XML structure on an example.

Comment: I have added the relevant xml code. As you can see there are some elements that get repeated like alternative title and subject. If I can get them to show up in their own column and cell in Excell, or ; separated in one cell, either would be good. I have lots of xml files to covert, so ultimately, I may need to find a findall() solution for additional elements just to be safe that I am not leaving any data behind. Thanks again!!

Comment: Maybe XSLT and pandas could make your job easier.  You can maybe open another question, how you can flatten your structure for pandas and XSLT.