# How do I return a reference to a dynamic type from C++ and hold it in Python?

Tags: c++, python, boost-python

I'm writing some code that returns a column value from a row based on the column index.  The row is updated from time to time in C++, and I'd like the python code to keep a reference to the column value.  The following code reflects my current solution, in which I have to repeatedly fetch the column value.

```
struct Foo
{
   PyObject * get(int pos)
   {
       // Position 0 is an integer value.  Position 1 is a float value
       if (pos == 0)
           return Py_BuildValue ("i", m_int);
       else
           return Py_BuildValue ("f", m_float);
   }
   void set_int(int i)
   {
       m_int = i;
   }
   void set_float(float f)
   {
       m_float = f;
   }
   int m_int;
   float m_float;
};
```

My bindings are simple:

```
class_<Foo> ("Foo")
        .def("get", &Foo::get)
        .def("set_int", &Foo::set_int)
        .def("set_float", &Foo::set_float)
        ;
```

This works at the python level like this:

```
In [16]: foo = Foo()
In [17]: foo.set_int(1)
In [18]: foo.set_float(2.5)
In [19]: i = foo.get(0)
In [20]: f = foo.get(1)
In [21]: i
Out[21]: 1

In [22]: type(i)
Out[22]: int

In [23]: f
Out[23]: 2.5

In [24]: type(f)
Out[24]: float
```

So far, so good.  However, when I modify foo, I'd like i and f to reflect the new values.  Currently, they reflect the old values.

```
In [25]: foo.set_int(42)
In [26]: i
Out[26]: 1
```

How do I setup the C++ and binding code so that 'get' returns a reference to rather than a copy of the Foo member variables?

Comment: Python's semantics are strictly pass-by-value. Work with references to `Foo` instead.

Comment: That's a reasonable suggestion.  I'll see if I can work that out.  Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to wrap the integer values in an object class. Primitives are immutable in Python so when you return an int value it will never reference the original int, just a const copy. You could return a new struct of the form:

```
struct IntWrap {
     int *value;
     int get() { return *value; }
     void set_int(int nval) { *value = nval; }
     ...
};

class_<IntWrap > ("IntWrap")
     .def("get", &IntWrap::get)
     .set("set_int", &IntWrap::set_int)
     ...
```

and make wrapper function bindings that treat the struct as a mutable integer in Python. This however, does violate the constness idiom of primitives in Python.

Here's a [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2673651/inheritance-from-str-or-int) on effectively inheriting from `str` or `int`, where you could make changes to the integer style object to use IntWrap instead (in case you want something that acts more like an `int` out of the box).

Comment: I follow the code you've included.  However, what return type would I use for Foo::get?  Sometimes it would return IntWrap and sometimes FloatWrap.

Comment: @D.A. It should return an abstract interface that returns a `Py_Object*`, and the actual implementation would use the appropriate `Py_BuildValue` call and otherwise disambiguate between the two cases.