# python the difference between class(dict) and class(str)

Tags: python

I am wondering what kind of difference exists between class(dict) and class(str)
Here is my code

```
class MyDict3(str):
     def __init__(self):
         self.a = None 

class MyDict(dict):
     def __init__(self):
         self.a = None
```

These classes are what I made for clarification
and then I type below

```
>>> mydict['a'] = 1
>>> mydict
{'a': 1}
>>> mydict3['a'] = 1
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: 'MyDict3' object does not support item assignment
```

Why does my mydict3['a'] make an error?
The difference that I made is only MyDict(dict) and MyDict(str)
As far as I know, the object that I specified(dict, str) is just nothing but constructer like c++,java

Please give me a clear answer on that.

Comment: `MyDict3(str)` means that MyDict3 inherits from `str`, `MyDict3(dict)` inherits from `dict`. It'd be like `class MyDict3 extends String` in Java.

Comment: String objects don't support item assignment.

Comment: I got it, Thank you guys.

Comment: Not sure why you expected `mydict3['a']` to work in the first place. Strings don't support item assignment; you only gave instances an `a` *attribute*. `So `mydict3.a` and `mydict.a` both exist (your `mydict['a']` *item* is independent from the `a` attribute).

Comment: You'll also have trouble with `__init__` in `str`, as strings are immutable. See [inheritance from str or int](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2673651).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> *Why does my mydict3['a'] make an error? The difference that I made is only MyDict(dict) and MyDict(str) As far as I know, the object that I specified(dict, str) is just nothing but constructer like c++,java*

I believe that you're doing a confusion here, thinking that a class attribute and an item are the same thing, like the following javascript code:

```
> foo = {'a': 42};
{ a: 42 }
> foo.a
42
> foo['a']
42
> foo.a === foo['a']
true
```

But in python `foo.a` and `foo['a']` are two different mechanisms. When you call `foo.a` you're actually accessing the `a` attribute of a class, which is defined through the class definition:

```
class Foo:
    def __init__(self):
        self.a = 42 # declaring and defining the a attribute
```

so then you can access it using:

```
 >>> foo = Foo()
 >>> print(foo.a)
 42
```

But to have `foo['a']` working, you have to use the indexing mechanism, which is usually used for dicts or lists:

```
>>> foo = {'a': 42}
>>> foo['a']
42
```

That mechanism is being implemented by the [`__getitem__`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/operator.html#operator.__getitem__) method of your class, so you can overload it if you want:

```
class Foo:
    def __getitem__(self, val):
        if val == 'a':
            return 42
        raise KeyError('Unknown key') # when the key is unknown, you raise a key error exception

>>> foo = Foo()
>>> foo['a']
42
>>> foo['b']
KeyError: 'Unknown key'
```

So, the `dict` class is a class that implements `__getitem__` (and `__setitem__` and many others), in order to provide you a proper mapping mechanism called a dictionary. There keys can be any immutable objects, and values anything. For a list, it shall be only integers (which are the positions in the list).

That being said, let's answer your question:

> *Why does my mydict3['a'] make an error?*

obviously it's because you defined `mydict3` as being an implementation of a string, which has a special implementation for the `__getitem__` method: it's giving you a character at the parameter position like if the list was a list of character (like in C).

So when you're trying to index `mydict3` with `'a'`, python just tells you that what you're asking makes no sense!

So in the end, when you say:

> *The difference that I made is only MyDict(dict) and MyDict(str)*

it's actually a very big difference! A `dict` and an `str` do not have the same interface, and thus what you want to do cannot work!

---

P.S.: Actually, nothing is black or white. The implementation of a class actually is a dict, and you can access all members of a class' instance through the `__dict__` member of an instance:

```
class Foo():
    def __init__(self):
        self.a = 42

>>> foo = Foo()
>>> foo.__dict__['a']
42
```

but you shall never directly access the `__dict__` instance directly, and use helper functions `setattr` and `getattr`:

```
>>> setattr(foo, 'b', 42)
>>> getattr(foo, 'b')
42
>>> getattr(foo, 'a')
42
```

This is some advanced python tricks, and they should be use with care. If there's *really* no other way to do it, then maybe you should use that.

Also, there exists a special class that transform dict items as class members, it's the [`namedtuple`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/collections.html?highlight=namedtuple#collections.namedtuple):

```
>>> from collections import namedtuple
>>> d = {'a': 42, 'b': 69}
>>> SpecialDict = namedtuple('SpecialDict', d.keys())
>>> foo = SpecialDict(**d)
>>> d.a
42
>>> d.b
69
```

HTH