# TypeError when extending a class with additional attributes

Tags: python, python-3.x, inheritance

I want to extend the standard python `bytes` class with some additional attributes, so that I can handle them like any normal `bytes` objext (e.g. putting them into a list and sort them).

Thus I created my own class that inherits from `bytes` and overrode the constructor to take additional attributes, setting them before invoking the parent class (`bytes`) constructor.

```py
class inheritest(bytes):
    def __init__(self, bs: bytes, x: int = 0):
        print("child class init")
        self.x = x
        super().__init__(bs)


print(inheritest(b'foobar', 3))
```

This approach does not work: I get a type error about a wrong argument signature being passed to the `bytes` constructor, although I only invoke it in line 5 with a single argument of the type `bytes`, which should be fine.
Even more, note that the print statement is never executed, so the constructor of the `inheritest` class is never executed but the argument type signature check, raising the TypesError, seems to happen beforehand.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "inheritest.py", line 8, in <module>
    print(inheritest(b'foobar', 3))
TypeError: bytes() argument 2 must be str, not int
```

So what am I doing wrong about inheritance and attribute extension?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TLDR: You are incorrectly overwriting `__init__` instead of `__new__`.

```
class XBytes(bytes):
    __slots__ = 'x',  # avoid arbitrary attributes

    def __new__(cls, bs: bytes, x: int = 0):
        # call original __new__ with expected signature
        self = super().__new__(cls, bs)
        self.x = x
        return self
```

---

Python types canonically have *two* methods that are used when constructing an object:

- `__new__` creates the object ("constructor")
- `__init__` creates the state ("initialiser")

Notably, both are called when creating an object. You can think of constructing an instance of `Class` (e.g. `Class(1, 2, 3)`) as equivalent to this:

```
def new(cls, *args, **kwargs):
    """same as ``cls(*args, **kwargs)``"""
    self = cls.__new__(cls, *args, **kwargs)
    if isinstance(self, cls):
       cls.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
```

Note how `__new__` *creates* an object, while `__init__` only *changes* it. For **immutable types, you must override `__new__`** since they cannot be changed.

---

If you override `__init__`, the signature of `__new__` is not changed! When calling `inheritest(b'foobar', 3)`, the arguments `b'foobar', 3` are passed to the original `bytes.__new__`. This happens *before* your custom `__init__` is called, thus never triggering `print`.

Comment: Thank you. Could it be that `__new__` is usually left out in all literature teaching python? Never heard of its role in object creation before.

Comment: Teaching material generally focuses only on subclassing ``object``, since it is the most common. The more complex parts of the Python object model are generally ignored. You can find more information in the docs (https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__new__) and there are some tutorials around if you specifically look for ``__new__``.

Answer (score 2):

you need to override `__new__` in order to inherit from bytes:

```
class MyBytes(bytes):
    def __new__(cls, *args, **kwargs):
        self = super().__new__(cls, *args, *kwargs)
        return self
```

now to extend as you would like i suggest this:

```
class MyBytes(bytes):
    def __new__(cls, source, x):
        self = super().__new__(cls, source)
        self.x = x
        return self

    def __str__(self):
        return f"<{repr(self)}, {self.x}>"


b = MyBytes(b"", 3)
print(b)  # <b'', 3>
b = MyBytes(b"345", 5)
print(b)  # <b'345', 5>
```

note:

- i ignored the other arguments `bytes` would accept (`encoding` and `errors`)
- `__str__` only works as long as you do not override `__repr__`.
- instances of `MyByte` are mutable now; depending on what you need you may either avoid that `x` can be changed (with a `property`) and set the `__slots__` attribute for the class -  or provide a `__hasĥ__` method that takes `x` into account.

---

this would also work:

```
class MyBytes(bytes):
    def __new__(cls, source, x):
        self = super().__new__(cls, source)
        return self

    def __init__(self, source, x):
        self.x = x
```

Comment: @ReblochonMasque i'd say along the lines of this: `bytes` is immutable; therfore it is too late to initialize an instance when `__init__` is called.

Comment: oh, this answer may be more to the point: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2673863/4954037